# CSS to button_to_remote rails function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is for a button to make a ajax call. I am trying to add CSS to the button to no avail.

```
<%= button_to_remote "Close sales period",:url=>{:controller=>'admin',:action=>"closure"},:class=>"button close"   %>


.close_sales_period
{
    background: url(/images/buttons/close_sales_period.gif) no-repeat;
}

.button
{
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  width:152px;
  height:26px;
  font-size:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color:transparent;
  display:inline;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

`button_to_remote` need two hashes of params, so the first hash must be explicitly enclosed in brackets. Try this:

```
<%= button_to_remote "Close sales period", {:url=> {:controller=>'admin',:action=>"closure"}},:class=>"button close" %>
```

(note the pair of brackets)

And, please, use named routes.